# value change when exceed number of character

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out when a value in column exceed number of character, it will change a value in another column. For example, in the 'Body' column, whenever the row in the csv exceed number of character of 156, it will change the value of 1 in another column name 'Double'.

Example of Dataframe:

```
                       Body                                           Double
Hello John, What is your name again? Can you check                       0
it now for the exam later?                                               
Dear Mr Sammy, I've found out about the exam that Mr                     0
Wick failed on last semester, would you think of 
any recommendation?
```

Above is an example of my csv files. In the 'Body' column, I've set filtered on which character that have  `.str.len(156)` in the 'Body' column. If I put 'RM0' in front of the text, and it exceed the amount of character, it will assign value of 1 in the 'Double' column. (**assuming in the body column contains number of character of 156**)

Below is my current code;

```
 for p5 in df:
        if df[(df['BDE'] == '0') & (df['ADD'].isull())]:
           df.loc[df['Body'].gt(156), 'Double'] = '1'
```

The 'BDE' and the 'ADD' is just a matter of filtering the column purpose.

My desired output:

```
                        Body                                     Double
RM0 Hello John, What is your name again? Can you check             1
it now for the exam later?
```

I'm quite new to pandas and a less than a month of grasp with python, hence, appreciate if you could highlight my mistake and recommend any suggestion to achieve my desired output.

**ERROR occured after tried with: **

```
df.loc[(df['BDE'] == '0') & (df['ADD'].isull()) & df['Body'].str.len().gt(156), 'Double'] = '1'
```

TRACEBACK:

```
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/syafiq/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/syafiq/Downloads/RoutingPractice01.py", line 80, in main
    df.loc[(df['BDE'] == '0') & (df['ADD'].isull()) & df['Body'].str.len().gt(156), 'Double'] = '1'
  File "/Users/syafiq/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/syafiq/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'BDE'
```

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need chain another condition with `&` for bitwise AND:

```
df.loc[(df['BDE'] == '0') & (df['ADD'].isull()) & df['Body'].gt(156), 'Double'] = '1'
```

Or:

```
df.loc[(df['BDE'] == '0') & (df['ADD'].isull()) & df['Body'].str.len().gt(156), 'Double'] = '1'
```

Comment: HI @jezrael, I didn't realise can put into together for .str.len().gt, I've tried it, however, it gave me an error 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: @SyafiqRosli - What means `The 'BDE' and the 'ADD' is just a matter of filtering the column purpose. ` ? Becaue error mean ther is no column `BDE` and `ADD`, do you need something different?

Comment: the BDE and ADD is just to niche down the filtering of the column, there is a column name 'BDE' and 'ADD'

Comment: @SyafiqRosli - hmmm, `KeyError: 'BDE'` means no column `BDE`, what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: After you've mentioned it, now I realised why. Because this line code after I did my concatenation task and group by columns, which currently df only consist certain column where BDE does not in the current df.

Comment: @SyafiqRosli - OK, then omit `(df['BDE'] == '0') &`